# How to add blank HTML page to Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

I'm trying to figure out how to add a blank HTML page to Magento, so that I can drop in some HTML content without Magento trying to inject its own code/layout.

I do not want to use the exisiting magento layout that I have for this page -- I want this page to be entirely blank and only load the HTML content/scripts that I drop in.

I've tried just adding the content via the HTML editor under the content section, and under the meta data section I've set the theme to blank and layout to empty, but when the page loads all of the HTML I added via the WSYWIG editor, it is stripped out. If I save the page, then go back in and click the HTML button, all the HTML I added is gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time the WYSIWYG editor runs it strips out lots of HTML, to protect you from yourself.  You can prevent it from running automatically in *System > Configuration > Content Management > WYSIWYG Options*.  Change "Enabled by default" to "Disabled by default" then you will be able to edit the page without it breaking itself.

(Also try installing [Lesti Version](http://gordonlesti.com/lestiversion/) so you can rollback if you lose some work)

However, that defeats the purpose of using such a capable framework.  If all you want is to work with raw HTML then save an HTML file and upload it the old fashioned way, through FTP.  You are not forced to use Magento for every detail of your site.

Comment: I'm new to Magento, didn't even realize I could just upload the HTML file via FTP. It appears though that if I create a folder like 'products' and I drop my index.html file in that folder, I'm not able to access the file via the URL /products, it makes me go to /products/index.html. Is this a magento setting or is there anyway to configure this so I can access the page at /products?

Comment: That is because the path `/products` isn't really the address of anything. `/parents/` is the address of a directory, and `/parents/index.html` is the address of a file.  Indefinite URLs get passed to Magento instead.  To change that means editing the `.htaccess` file, you should start a new question about it specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Design Tab for your CMS Page and set the Layout to "Empty"? BTW on Content tab, you need to at least type a `&nbsp;` in order to save the page.

Comment: That works fine if you set the layout to empty, however, if you save the page with the HTML you added on the content tab through the WSYWIG editor, it removes the HTML.